# JScrollPane doesn't work (MigLayout)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, miglayout

I am trying to put a `JScrollPane` to a `JTable` with `Miglayout` but if I compile it, the `JScrollpane` doesn't work (So there are no arrows and so on...) .

Here is my code:

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    final String[] cols = {"", "", ""};
    final Object[][] data = {
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
            {new ImageIcon(), new String(), new String(), new JPanel()},
    };

    public int setRowHeight() {
        return 50;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return cols.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return cols[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return false;
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        data[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        System.out.println("setVal" + value); // da sind die Daten!
    }

    static void create() {
        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("debug,fill");
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        //Button
        JButton addRow = new JButton("Add Row");
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("test OK");
            }
        });

        p.setLayout(layout);
        p.setBackground(Color.RED);

        MyTableModel mod = new MyTableModel();

        JTable table = new JTable(mod);

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);

        JTableHeader tableHeader = table.getTableHeader();

        tableHeader.setReorderingAllowed(false);
        tableHeader.setResizingAllowed(true);

        table.setValueAt(new ImageIcon("C:\\redIcon.png"), 0, 2);
        table.setRowHeight(40);

        p.add(tableHeader, "dock north");
        p.add(table, "dock center");
        p.add(pane, "dock east");

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setSize(600, 300);
        f.setContentPane(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert those 2 lines below your scrollpane:

```
pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

This adds scrollbars for up/down and left/right.

BUT your code is a bit convoluted, it's hard to see what you really want to accomplish. Especially the part, where you add lots and lots of JPanels seems odd and looks visually buggy.

Answer (score 1):

```
JTable table = new JTable(mod);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
JTableHeader tableHeader = table.getTableHeader();
//...
p.add(tableHeader, "dock north");
p.add(table, "dock center");
p.add(pane, "dock east");
```

These components don't work that way...

The tableHeader is a part of the table, you can't just "rip it off" and render it independently somewhere else.

The table is added to the scrollPane, it doesn't make sense to then add the scrollPane and the table separately in different locations.

```
JTable table = new JTable(mod);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
//...
p.add(pane, "dock center");
```

Should be all you need to do - add the table to the scrollPane, then add the scrollPane to the center of the panel.

Comment: wow that was the solution sir :) !! I am a java beginner and trying some experiments with jtable and so on :) thanks a lot !